# Is there a way to check if a build is in Adhoc, release, distribution programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, build, adhoc

Like the title says, I need a way to detect if the build is in adhoc, release or distribution since I am using keychain-access-groups for each type of build I am using a different provisiong so the bundle seed id are different. I just need an effective way to switch this on certain build.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to the target you want to test, then build settings and search for preprocessing and you should see something like this:

[image]

As you can see debug already has a value. You can enter RELEASE=1 if you want to check for a release build. Then in your code drop in an if statement like this:

```
#if DEBUG==1
// do debug build settings stuff there
#endif

#if RELEASE==1
// do release build settings stuff there
#endif
```

Comment: To check for release build, do #ifndef DEBUG. No need to add RELEASE macro.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a Custom Build Setting (aka define), which will have different values in different build configurations?